# How to make User information available to service layer

Tags: asp.net-web-api

What is the best way to make web user info e.g. username, userId available to the service / db layers in order to stamp records with edited/updated by information? without individually passing this info with every call.

Comment: Pass this info this the best way, think about in future you need to refactor to support your service/layer in different processes (like windows services), it will come to trouble. Also, passing this info, it would be easier for testing

Answer (score 0):

An api is stateless. In addition to this, you don't "login" to an api in order to use it and can't expect that kind of information to be available to the api on later requests.

You might use some other mechanism, you might provide a username and a password which are validated to make sure they are correct but that's about as far as you will go.

If your api is secured with something like OAuth2, then you will pass an authorization token which each request. To that token you would add whatever data you need, like username and userid and then you can extract them and add them to your other layers as required.

If you don't use such a system then whoever calls the api will need to pass the extra data with every request somehow anyway, otherwise the API has no idea where the request is coming from.

Comment: My question probably wasn't very clear, i was talking about getting user info from token in the api, then make that info available in the service layer without having to add it to method calls